# Ajouter champ grid order

Tags: magento-1.9

Bonjour, je souhaite ajouter le champ total remboursé qui est visible dans une commande client.
Pourriez-vous m'aider ? Je suis sous Magento 1.9

```
 $this->addColumn('total_refunded', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total remboursé'),
        'index' => 'total_refunded',
        'width' => '25px',
        'align' => 'center',
    ));

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
  $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address',
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',
        array('telephone','city','postcode','country_id'))
        ->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type =  'billing'");
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
```

Comment: Please ak question at english

Answer (score 0):

Remplacez votre `collection`, par`le code ci-dessous:`

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
  $collection->getSelect()
            ->join('sales_flat_order_address',
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id',
        array('telephone','city','postcode','country_id'))
            ->join('sales_flat_order',
            'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',
        array('total_refunded'))
        ->where("sales_flat_order_address.address_type =  'billing'");
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

et `ajouter un code` avec ceci:

```
$this->addColumn('total_refunded', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total remboursé'),
        'index' => 'total_refunded',
        'filter_index'=>'main_table.increment_id',
        'width' => '25px',
        'align' => 'center',
    ));
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'increment_id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id WHERE (sales_flat_order_address.address_type =  'billing') AND (increment_id LIKE '%31181%')

Comment: mis à jour ma réponse, contrôle de pls